# How to restrict other user group members to view the Documents

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-aui

I have created an Organization which has four user groups. I want to restrict the user group to view the file uploaded by the other user group.

i.e

- Organization 1

  - User Group 1

    - A
    - B
  - User Group 2

    - C
    - D
  - User Group 3

    - E
    - F
  - User Group 4

    - G
    - H

I am using CustomLanding hook to land on the organization page.

From above, If A uploads a document, it can be viewed only by B in user group 1.

Like the same I want to restrict the viewable condition to other groups also.

Please guide me to achieve this.

Regards,
Dinesh.

Answer (score 0):

you can create different roles for the user and apply permission for role.
Instead of taking as user group with in organization we have teams. you can try with teams.